# Loop through cells and move columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code which evaluates number of cells and changes their font colour according table.

I am able to do within a column but I need to go through whole table.

I cannot figure out how to move between columns "B becomes C" etc.

If I play with for each column logic I'm struggling to assign the variable which should be vlookup'ed (?)

Any hints?

```
Sub AddColours()


Dim TPrange As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim Vlookup As String
Dim Colour As String
Dim CLR As Range
Dim FC As String
Dim LR_of_AJM As Integer
Dim COL As String



LR = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
B = 1
A = 1
c = 4 'first line of lookup text
x = Sheet2.Rows.Count


' counts last row

For Each Column In Sheet4.Range("b:G").Columns

LR_of_AJM = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows(Sheet4.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
COL = Sheet4.UsedRange.Columns(Sheet4.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column

Do While c < Sheet4.Range("a1")  'LR_of_AJM - 6 needs to be replaced by LR_of_AJM to do full loop

Sheet4.Activate
Set TPrange = Sheet2.Range("B2:Z" & LR)
'==================================

Set CLR = Sheet4.Range("b" & c)

'===========================================


Set CTP = Sheet3.Range("a1:b10")

On Error Resume Next
Colour = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(CLR, TPrange, 2, False)

FC = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Colour, CTP, 2, False)

CLR.Select

 With Selection.Font
    If FC = "Red" Then
        Selection.Font.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf FC = "Blue" Then
        Selection.Font.Color = vbBlue
         ElseIf FC = "Yellow" Then
        Selection.Font.Color = vbYellow
         ElseIf FC = "Green" Then
        Selection.Font.Color = vbGreen
       
        Else: Selection.Interior.Color = vbBlack
              End If
              
    End With


c = c + 1

Loop

'MsgBox "It has matched " & LR & " rows from Touchpoints sheet"

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Read up on 'for each' so that you enumerate a set of columns and then the set of cells withing each column.

Comment: Is your problem that you don't know how to iterate through the columns of a table?

Comment: correct - very unsure how to change variable for column to work. B = B+1 loop does not work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your situation is something like the image below :

[image]

expected result: 
[image]

The code below using find method instead of vlookup.

```
Sub test()
Dim LR As Integer
Dim CTP As Range, TPrange As Range, CLR As Range, cell As Range
Dim arrColor: Dim c as range: Dim d as range

arrColor = Array("Red", vbRed, "Blue", vbBlue, "Green", vbGreen, "Yellow", vbYellow)

LR = 7
Set CTP = Sheet3.Range("a1:b10")
Set TPrange = Sheet2.Range("B2:Z" & LR)
Set CLR = Sheet4.Range("B4:D7")

For Each cell In TPrange.Columns(1).Cells
    Set c = CLR.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    Set d = CTP.Find(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not c Is Nothing And Not d Is Nothing Then
        With CLR
            .Replace cell.Value, True, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
            Set rgR = .SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlLogical)
            .Replace True, cell.Value, xlWhole, , False, , False, False
        End With
        rgR.Font.Color = arrColor(Application.Match(d.Offset(0, 1), arrColor, False))
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It create the color item in array as arrColor variable.
Since you are using vlookup, logically the rows in TPRange column 1 are unique value. So it loop each cell in TPRange column 1 as cell variable, check if the looped cell is found in CLR range and the looped cell.offset(0,1) is found in CTP range then apply the color (by getting the index number in arrColor using match method)  to all cells which value is the looped cell value within CLR range.